# Pronunciation of “Flamant”

Tags: prononciation, noms-de-famille

I am confused with pronunciation of “*Flamant*”. I know this word is French but I am not sure about its pronunciation.

First I saw the word in [*Introduction to Continuum Mechanics*](http://books.google.com/books?id=lEhh-hjG6EgC&pg=PA316&dq=flamont%20problem&hl=en&sa=X&ei=20wnU7SjDomQtAa3ioH4BQ&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=flamont%20problem&f=false).

Comment: I'm sorry about the weird edit. The book you linked to says *Flamont*, but Wikipedia has *Flamant*, and I'm going to trust the latter source.

Comment: I have to say I am quite befuddled as to how there could possibly be any confusion as to the pronunciation of either spellings...

Comment: @Kareen Yes, your are right. I forgot to mention it. In errata file, the publisher has corrected this. I am sure, the correct spelling is **Flamant**.

Comment: @Circeus Dear Circeus, I am not French. Could you help me find its correct pronunciation?

Comment: Listen to it [here](http://shtooka.net/search.php?str=flamand&lang=fra). Spelling's different but pronunciation’s exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a last name so the pronunciation might be irregular. However, it happens to be either an old way to write Flamand, i.e. "Flemish" or the homonymous and possibly related "Flamingo" so it is expected to be simply pronounced /flamɑ̃/

Comment: Do you mean that two last letters i.e. **nt** are silent?

Comment: @Shaqpad The *t* is silent, but the *n* interacts with the *a* to make the nasalization /ɑ̃/ as opposed to the open /a/ or /ɑ/ if it weren't there.

Comment: Yes it's almost like Flamon using plain english letters. There is a French Radio personality called Flavie Flamant (she's an ex Miss Normandy) and the name seems to be derived from Flamand as suggested by Jilagre.